# Create function which take objects that declare an implicit writes

Tags: scala, playframework

*This is a dumbed-down example of my problem, ignore the semantics of the question*

I have two sets of objects that each define an implicit `writes` function:

```
case class User(id: Int, name: String)                      // Defines an implicit writes
case class Group(id: Int, membersCount: Int, adminID: Int)  // Defines an implicit writes
```

How can I create a function that accepts any parameter that defines an implicit writes function?  So that I can pass an instance of either object to that function:

```
def format(w: DefinesWrites): JsValue = {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the implicit `Writes` as an additional implicit parameter:

```
def format[T](w: T)(implicit wr: Writes[T]): JsValue = ???
```

If there is an implicit `Writes[T]` available in scope at the point where you call this function it will be passed automatically. But this won't compile if there is no `Writes[T]` available.

For example:

```
val user = User(1, "user")
format(user) // works if there is an implicit Writes[User] in scope.
```

You can also use an equivalent shorthand syntax with a [context bound](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-and-view-bounds.html):

```
def format[T: Writes](w: T): JsValue = ???
```

Comment: I'm getting compilation errors now complaining that there are no Json Serializers for type T:

`No Json serializer found for type T. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.`

This is what I am trying to work around, I want to make sure that everything I get can be transformed into JSON (I thought that was done via the implicit writes)

Comment: @Tyler This means there is no implicit `Writes[T]` available in scope, when you call `format`. If you have defined the requried implicit `Writes` somewhere, try either to import it, or to define it in the companion object of type `T` (e.g. `case class User(id: Int); object User { implicit val writes: Writes[User] = /* your definition here */ }`)